# Go: json encoding struct with pointers is slower than with copies?

Tags: json, pointers, go

I have the following test code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Coll1 struct {
    A string
    B string
    C string
}

type Coll2 struct {
    A *string
    B *string
    C *string
}

var as = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
var bs = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
var cs = "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

func testBM1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i<b.N; i++ {
        json.Marshal(Coll1{as,bs,cs})
    }
}

func testBM2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i<b.N; i++ {
        json.Marshal(Coll2{&as,&bs,&cs})
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(testing.Benchmark(testBM1))
    fmt.Println(testing.Benchmark(testBM2))
}
```

I would expect the second case to run faster since it is using pointers and therefore doesn't have to copy the strings, but in fact it runs at about 4250 ns/op where the first runs near 2800 ns/op. Can anyone shed any light on why this might be?

Edit: Darshan Computing suggested that this may hold true for embedded structs even. A simple test confirms this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"                  
    "encoding/json"            
) 

type Coll1 struct {
    A,B,C string
}

type Coll1Outer struct {
    A,B,C Coll1
}

type Coll2Outer struct {
    A,B,C *Coll2
}

type Coll2 struct {
    A,B,C *string
}

var as = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
var bs = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
var cs = "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

func testBM1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i<b.N; i++ {
        c := Coll1Outer{ Coll1{as,bs,cs}, 
                         Coll1{as,bs,cs},                
                         Coll1{as,bs,cs} }               
        json.Marshal(c)
    }
}

func testBM2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i<b.N; i++ {
        c := Coll2Outer{ &Coll2{&as,&bs,&cs},
                         &Coll2{&as,&bs,&cs},            
                         &Coll2{&as,&bs,&cs} }           
        json.Marshal(c)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(testing.Benchmark(testBM1))
    fmt.Println(testing.Benchmark(testBM2))
}
```

For me this shows the non-pointer struct taking about 12ms/op, while the one with pointers takes 13ms/op. Not a huge difference, but it's interesting that the property still holds.

Comment: I rewrote your code to take advantage of the inbuilt benchmarking features (see http://play.golang.org/p/90fYFCSjN9) and I got 3729 ns/op for the first and 4600 ns/op for the second on win8_64, still seems wrong, but the values are closer.

Comment: And, if I replace the `json.Marshal` calls with `_ = fmt.Sprintf` calls, I get 11990 ns/op & 7098 ns/op respectively (making pointers almost 70% faster). There's something going on in the json.Marshall function that slows it down when using pointers.

Comment: After a bit more research I think it's because the `marshal` function in `encoding/json` calls `reflect.ValueOf()` on the input interface (http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/encode.go?s=7722:7964#L230) which, may be slower if it needs to find the type of a value represented by a pointer, rather than directly on the value itslef. Just a guess though.

Comment: Thanks intermernet! Your answer seems to coincide with darshan's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the biggest percentage difference in ns/op when I set `as`, `bs`, and `cs` to `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`, respectively.  As I increase the length of the strings, they approach each other.  They seem to always be about 1000 ns/op different.

So I believe all that's going on is that it takes 1000 ns on my machine (1450 on yours) to reflect and follow the pointers.  Passing a smaller struct up front doesn't seem to counteract this effect because once the pointers are followed, `Marshal` still passes the data around internally in the process of generating and returning the equivalent JSON.

Comment: That makes sense, I hadn't thought about the fact that it's going to need some sort of reflection. For a larger, embedded system of structs (multiple layers deep, many fields) would I be correct in assuming that pointers would usually end up being faster in that case?

Comment: @MediocreGopher My guess is that the same pattern would hold even for complex structs, but I'd certainly be interested in the results if you test it out.

Comment: I edited my original question with a basic test case for embedded structs, looks like you're right. I'm still curious about why reflection on pointers takes so long to do. I presume the reflection has to be done on even the non-pointer types, is it just that the non-pointers don't necessarily require an extra "hop" to get to the real data?